# expl3: How to display the line number in a warning message

Tags: expl3, warnings, line, number

Beginning with LaTeX3, I would like to log this warning

```
Package foo Warning: blablabla on line XXX
```

I suspect `\msg_line_context` would help but how to use it ?
In the next MWE, it is not expanded

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_new:nnnn {foo} {warning-message} {blablabla #1} {}
\msg_warning:nnnnnn {foo} {warning-message} {\msg_line_context} {} {} {}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
TEST
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\msg_warning:nnn` function doesn't expand the arguments. Instead use `\msg_warning:nnx` if you want expansion.

Comment: Why not `\msg_new:nnn {foo} {warning-message} { blablabla \msg_line_context: }` and then just `\msg_warning:nn {foo} {warning-message}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
\documentclass{article}
%\RequirePackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_new:nnn {foo} {warning-message} {blablabla #1}
\msg_warning:nnx {foo} {warning-message} {~\msg_line_context:}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
TEST
\end{document}
```

With this setup you get

```
Package foo Warning: blablabla on line 6
```

Note that `\msg_warning:<signature>` is available with various signatures:

- `nnnnnn` (four variable arguments)
- `nnxxxx` (four expanded variable arguments)
- `nnnnn` (three variable arguments)
- `nnxxx` (three expanded variable arguments)
- `nnnn` (two variable arguments)
- `nnxx` (two expanded variable arguments)
- `nnn` (one variable argument)
- `nnx` (one expanded variable argument)
- `nn` (no argument)

In the third argument to `\msg_new:nnn` you're allowed to use `#1` up to `#4` to refer to arguments given to the particular flavor of `\msg_warning:<signature>` you'll use.

For instance, if you call

```
\msg_warning:nn {foo} {warning-message}
```

you'll only get

```
Package foo Warning: blablabla
```

On the other hand, if you plan to always have the line number in the warning, it makes sense to do

```
\msg_new:nnn {foo} {warning-message} {blablabla~\msg_line_context:}
\msg_warning:nn {foo} {warning-message}
```